# Converting nested list into dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, nested

Learning a new thing here - I've been trying to tackle a problem all day and haven't had much success.  The idea is to loop through a nested list and return a dictionary.  However, the first element of the list contains the column headers for the dictionary values.  So here is the nested list, or table_data:

```
table_data = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
]
```

convert_table(table_data)

***I want to convert the nested list into a dictionary as seen below. Basically, I'd like a function to take in the nested list then spit out the output as shown below.***

```
[
    {"first_name": "Elisabeth", "last_name": "Gardenar", "city": "Toledo", "state": "OH"},
    {"first_name": "Jamaal", "last_name": "Du", "city": "Sylvania", "state": "OH"},
    {"first_name": "Kathlyn", "last_name": "Lavoie", "city": "Maumee", "state": "OH"}
]
```

Here is some of the code I've been fiddling with so far, but am kind of stuck on how to get the elements of the first index of the list to repeat and become key's for the values in the rest of the dictionary.

Thank you!

```
for i in range(len(table_data)):
    for j in table_data[0]:
        print(j)

for i in table_data:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Comment: You will probably get more responses if you included what language you are using in your tag list.  People have filters set to help people with languages that they know about.

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I neglected that, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being aware that Python dictionaries are inherently unordered you can do it this way:

```
lst = []
for row in table_data[1:]:
    lst.append(dict(zip(table_data[0],row)))
```

If you need to preserve order use an OrderedDict like so:

```
import collections as co

lst_ordered = []
for row in table_data[1:]:
    lst_ordered.append(co.OrderedDict(zip(table_data[0],row)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I'm a little confused as we are appending to a list.  I'm trying to build a function that returns a dictionary.  Basically, I'd like to convert a nested list to a dictionary with the column headings being the first index/indices of the first list.

Comment: You're welcome. This returns a list of dictionaries. Your question doesn't mention a function returning dictionaries so it might help to edit the question describing what you're envisioning in a little more detail.

Comment: Updated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bernie got this right.  Now I'm going to study it.  Thank you.

```
lst = []
for row in table_data[1:]:
    lst.append(dict(zip(table_data[0],row)))
```